# Any downside or ill effects of using useAbortableState instead of useState [custom hook] in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am way too irritated with the warning: `cannot update state on unmounted component`. And I have been using logic like:

```
const [mounted,setMounted] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
    return () => setMounted(false);
},[]);
if(mounted) setState(<newValue>);
```

Now these if statements are increasing in lots of places and so I decided to go with a custom hook as shown below:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

const useAbortableState = <T,>(initialValue: T): [T, (value: T) => void] => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => setMounted(false);
  }, []);

  const setNewValue = useCallback(
    (newValue: any) => {
      if (mounted) {
        setValue(newValue);
      }
    },
    [mounted]
  );

  return [value, setNewValue];
};

export default useAbortableState;
```

I am missing any performance stuff or some side effects which could be dangerous in this case. Can any expert confirm if I could use `useAbortableState` instead of `useState` everywhere in my components for state updates or should I go with `useState` with the `mounted` logic to play safe?

Also even though I am using the custom logic, I still get the `cannot update state on unmounted component` warning. I am not sure what I could be missing here?

Comment: This is safer way to use useState. The problem with react is they are not allowing any approach to cancel the async event of setState by default or programmatically. Though, This should not be a concern as it is dropped from react 18. Refer this link for in depth discussion on the topic. https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/22114

Comment: Your current approach will become a problem moving forward with new versions of react when they actually allow component to stay even though they are not visible. That will break the entire flow here as your component is not mounted but you'll still be able to set the state.

Comment: Hmm so you're saying that if I upgrade react and react-dom to 18 this warning will go away?

Comment: Yep, Do update here how it goes.